# access to input data from microphone in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

How can I access to input data from microphone in Windows Phone 7.0 or 7.1? (like a Volume Meter), i want to detect start and end input data from microphone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [How to: Access the Microphone in a Silverlight Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442302%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for basic usage.

If you want to detect the start and stop of certain audio input you'll have to parse/process the returned stream yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This blog post also has a great tutorial (and code) showing how you access the microphone in WP7 via XNA:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/08/27/xna-from-silverlight-on-windows-phone-7-the-microphone.aspx

Good luck!