# How to pick up the microphone in background in Windows phone programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Are there any code samples (C#) how to pick up and handle microphone sounds under Win Phone 7+ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [access to input data from microphone in WP7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075278/access-to-input-data-from-microphone-in-wp7)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not a duplicate. Because i need to use background mode in my program. And OS is blocking part of media libraries for programs in background mode.

Comment: how do you mean "background mode"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, windows phone as a number of [APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that can't be used on background agents, microphone is one of them.